# C# RSA Decryption Issue with Smart Card - Padding not removed from the result

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, smartcard

I'm using the RSACryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt simple strings and while it works with normal certificates, I'm facing troubles when it comes with smart cards.

Here is the code that I'm using:

Create the RSACryptoServiceProvider:

```
        public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetRSACSPSmartCard()
        {
            CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider", "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY");
            csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
            csp.KeyPassword = GetSmartCardPin();
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
            return rsa;
        }
```

Testmethod for encryption and decryption:

```
        private static void TestEnAndDecryption(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa)
        {
            byte[] toEncryptData;
            byte[] encryptedRSA;
            
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo);
            toEncryptData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world");
            encryptedRSA = rsa.Encrypt(toEncryptData, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
         
            string EncryptedResult = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encryptedRSA);
            Console.WriteLine(EncryptedResult);
            Console.WriteLine();

            byte[] decryptedRSA = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedRSA, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
            string originalResult = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedRSA);
            Console.WriteLine(originalResult);
        }
```

It does decrypt successfully but the in the result the padding is not removed:
[Output of the encryption/decryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maeYu.png)

What's also interesting is no matter what I encrypt, the decrypted byte[] length is always 256.
The same code works with a normal RSA key which is not from a smart card.

Does anyone of you have ever had a similar situation?

I'm grateful for any tips or support - Thanks.

Comment: Smart Cards have different address and data sizes (8, 16, 32, 64 bits) and you have to use the correct size.  The driver also have to be installed properly.  So these are the steps I use to debug a smart card 1) Open Smart Card with Window and read the card with a file explorer.  Once card is open with explorer it will stay open until you turn off machine. 2)  Read Card from a c# application (after unlocking with explorer) to verify the size of the address and data 3) Unlock card with c# application.

Comment: Check your supplier. This is a mistake in their CSP implementation. They use a RAW decrypt on the smart card (which is, kind of weirdly, relatively secure). However, their software should then perform the PKCS#1 unpadding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices. 
Currently I'm using OpenSC - is the issue there? Should I use CardOS? Or is the problem with the issuer of the smard card?